# How to add zero to nvarchar in base to id len

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The idea is when the ID=1, the column Code 001 and ID=10 the column Code 010 and finally I want that the column Code get the data of the Id, for that reason is the else.

```
create table test(
Id int,
Code as case when len(Id)=1 then '00'+Id when len(Id)=2 then '0'+Id Else Id End 
);
```

Comment: Now I have a trigger but im using the same code in 3 tables

Comment: Code is a nvarchar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need for `code` to be a string.  The simplest method uses `concat()`:

```
code as (case when len(Id) = 1 then concat('00', Id) 
              when len(Id) = 2 then concat('0', Id)
              else convert(varchar(255), Id)
         end)
```

Or more simply as:

```
code as (right(concat('000', id), 3))
```

Of course, this version doesn't handle `id` values larger than 999.

Comment: Bro, thank you, now I no longer replicate the code with triggers

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a version of SQL Server that supports it, the `format()` function has got you:

`select format(1, 'D3')`

Comment: About this function I have written before you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,alberto mora.
You can use funtion Right+concat, because using LEFT+Concat you don't get correct result:

```
   RIGHT(CONCAT('00',cast (Id AS NVARCHAR(MAX))),3)
```

OR using function Format:

```
  FORMAT(Id,'000')
```